# Sharepoint Online - "Sharing folders is disabled" popup message not allowing me to grant permissions to a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a folders within document libraries with unique permissions. I want to grant access to a particular user but when I go to grant permission I get the following message:

"Sharing folders is disabled
To enable sharing, disable the limited access lockdown mode feature on the Site Features page, or share individual files or the site instead."

Should I Deactivate "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"? And if I do what are the implications of turning this off?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: paulSP20132017, I have disabled Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature, while the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is active. I have not seen any issues due to this configuration, but I just did it today. Do you have any updates since your question was posted? Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, go for it, if you're ok with:

*Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-A2F2A5C2-093D-4897-8B7F-37F86D83DF04?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US*

> **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**
>
> When enabled, permissions for users with “limited access” permissions, such as Anonymous Users, are reduced, preventing access to Application pages including item properties or list views. Additionally, if a document, folder, or library has unique permissions, those users will not be able to:
>
> Use the drag and drop feature to upload documents
>
> Browse to the affected folder
>
> Use the Shared with feature
>
> Create calendar events from calendar lists connected in Outlook
>
> Open documents in the Office client
>
> Some callout features on documents and folders will not render as expected

Comment: @paulSP20132017 please consider marking this as answered to help the community and close this question.

Comment: So, still no actual specifics from Microsoft on what exactly the implications for "SharePoint Server Publishing" are, right?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround add user/group at site level, then on folder level stop inheriting permissions and remove user/groups not needed.
Also, deactivating feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" resolves the issue.

Comment: The trick to "narrow" permissions, by adding higher then removing lower, worked well for me.  And I didn't have to take the risk of turning off the lockdown mode.